# RF and encapsulation materials

Tags: rf, potting

I have a WiFi application that we need to encapsulate for environmental reasons. We did some test shoots with Krayden PA2692 since the molder had experience with it. It's a polyamide material. The datasheet didn't give any RF parameters, but searching indicates the dielectric constant should be in the 2.5-2.8 range. RF performance once encapsulated was about 30% of free air. Does anyone have any suggestions for classes of material or what parameters matter most?

Comment: Stray air capacitance effects on tuning or impedance matching are amplified by Dk, loss tangent, moisture absorption rate, adhesion, thermal conductance are most important.

Comment: There are many grades of polyamide and polyolefin

Comment: Also Parylene is used by some,